# Is there a way to combine where and where.not into one condition in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I have an `Event` model, that has `user_id` inside it. I want to select all objects of this model, with specified `user_id` but not including specific events. So I can do it with a query like that:

```
Event.where(user_id: user.id).where.not(id: id)
```

But can I combine these 2 `where` functions into one?

I know that if I need to find, for example, events with specified `id`s and `user_id`s, I can do it this way:

```
Event.where(user_id: user_id).where(id: id)
```

and I can compact it using one `where` call instead of two:

```
Event.where(user_id: user_id, id: id)
```

but can I do the same thing if I am using `where` and `where.not`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write as per below to add where and where.not :

```
Event.where(
  "user_id = ? AND id != ?",
  user.id,
  id
)
```

so if user_id = 1 and id = 2
than this will return records with user_id 1 and without id 2 :)

Answer (score 5):

You can gather

```
Event.where(user_id: 1) + Event.where.not(id: 2)
```

or deny a parameter

```
Event.where(user_id: 1).where.not(id: 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

try this,you can create two scopes and calling then in chain

```
scope :with_user, ->(user) {user_id: user.id}

scope :excluded_event, ->(event_ids) { where.not(id: event_ids) }

Event.with_user(user).excluded_event(event_ids)
```

Comment: True 'rubysh' answer =)